# Is the centralizer of a subgroup generated by two matrices itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm working on some subgroup commutativity and I came across the Heisemberg group modulo 3,

[image: Heisemberg group presentation]

This group has order 27 and my intuition leads me to believe the centralizer of each subgroup (except the center and the whole group) is equal to itself but as a mathematician I'd like to have certainty or a counterexample, thank you in advance.

Subgroups:

[image: Heisemberg subgroups]

Comment: Your list of subgroups is incomplete. A subgroup of order $3$ not equal to the centre has centralizer of order $9$, so not equal to itself. Also the centralizer of the whole group is not equal to itself.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I tried using the same format as in my LaTex compiler but it didn't work, I'll be sure to fix it soon

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, would you mind explaining which subgroup I'm missing?

Comment: For example the subgroup of order $3$ generated by the first generator of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to first list all of the subgroups. Let $x = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, y=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $H = \langle x,y \rangle$, and $\langle x \rangle, \langle y \rangle, \langle z \rangle, \langle xy \rangle, \langle yx \rangle, \langle xz \rangle, \langle yz \rangle$ are all cyclic subgroups of order 3, and $\langle x,z \rangle, \langle y,z \rangle, \langle xy,z \rangle$ are the subgroups isomorphic to $Z_3 \times Z_3$.

Since the statement "all subgroups of H are their own centralizer" doesn't hold for the cyclic groups of order 3 or $\{e\}$ or $H$, I will show how you can prove the statement in the affirmative for the groups isomorphic to $Z_3 \times Z_3$: $A = D = \langle x,z \rangle, B = \langle y,z \rangle$, and $C = \langle xy, z \rangle$.
To show that $C_H(A)=A$, notice that all elements in $H-A$ have a nonzero entry in position $(2,3)$. Let $w = \begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, c \neq 0 \in H-A$. Then $xw = \begin{bmatrix}1&\overline{a+1}&c\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \neq wx = \begin{bmatrix}1&\overline{a+1}&0\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. So, for any element $g \in H-A$, $g \notin C_H(A)$. And since $A$ is abelian, $A \subseteq C_H(A)$. Therefore, $C_H(A)=A$. You can make similar arguments for the subgroups $B$ and $C$.